# Sightly @ extension='html' adding a space a the end of the URL

Tags: sightly, aem-6

We're having a weird problem in our AEM 6.3 application.
For some reason, the link to the contact-us page gets rendered with a space at its end, making it useless.

I'm trying to figure this out but I'm kinda new to sightly (I used to be working on CQ5).

To visualize it better, the configured link in the page properties is:

```
/content/app-name/hk/hk/info/contact-us
```

And the code in the HTML/sightly page is:

```
<a href="${inheritedPageProperties.linkToContactUsPage @ extension='html'} ">
    Contact Us
</a>
```

While what gets rendered in the actual page is:

```
<a href="/hk/hk/info/contact-us%20.html">
    Contact Us
</a>
```

This happens only in the chinese pages of the site, I'm not sure if this is relevant or just a coincidence.

At first I thought the problem could be the blank space at the end of the href attribute, but shouldn't it result in "/hk/hk/info/contact-us.html%20" then? Also why would this problem affect only the chinese language pages and not all the other languages?

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT you do have a space in the page properties link:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you're selecting but no, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the space in your

`<a href="${inheritedPageProperties.linkToContactUsPage @ extension='html'} ">`

like this

`<a href="${inheritedPageProperties.linkToContactUsPage @ extension='html'}">`